# Getting sec_error_reused_issuer_and_serial while doing curl

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to curl an AWS instance using client certificate authentication.  Although the certificates are generated and shared correctly across boxes, I am getting sec_error_reused_issuer_and_serial error.

`curl -I -v --cert /pathToCert --key /pathToKey http://ip.to.aws.box`